# Prevent user from accessing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a button in my page which redirects the user to a form:

```
<button id="evaluationWait" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" style="display:none;"><a href="questionary.html"><h1 style="margin: 20px;">Evaluation</h1></a></button>
```

And I want if the computer, be it cellphone, tablet, lap, etc. has already clicked the button and visited the page with the questionary, then they can't do it again.

I was thinking of using localstorage as it would be the easiest way of getting if a user (device) has already clicked the button, like when you vote for something and you can't do it twice.

But how should I apply it. For the button I thought of disabling the button, setting the classes with localstorage, but is there a way of preventing the device from reaccessing the page or redirecting them?

Thanks

Comment: Not really.  The user could always edit the web page manually, or if they are slightly tech savy, investigate their network tab and re-send a previous web request.  You can make it harder for them to do, but if you don't want the same user to do the same action twice, that is going to have to involve some backend validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no reliable client side way to do this. There will never be a safe client side way to do checks like this. As a developer you should always remind yourself of the mantra *"never trust the client"*. The user can manipulate the client side in ways you can not control. So you have to handle important checks on the server side, always. In your example the user could simply use a different private browsing session every time and you can not know anything about the previous session, not even `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or cookies.